# Not a directory error while trying to start Tomcat in Linux

Tags: linux, tomcat, terminal, redhat

I have installed JDK, 1.7u45 and set the JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME and all.
After that I installed Apache Tomcat 1.6.37 and while I run the command

```
./catalina.sh run
```

It gives the following log on the terminal window.
Why is this happening?

```
bash-4.1$ ./catalina.sh run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/Desktop/apache-tomcat-6.0.37
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/Desktop/apache-tomcat-6.0.37
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/Desktop/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /home/Desktop/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/Desktop/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/bin/bootstrap.jar
Testing 2
./catalina.sh: line 309: /home/Desktop/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory
./catalina.sh: line 309: exec: /home/Desktop/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java/bin/java: cannot execute: Not a directory
```

Note : Testing 2 is just an echo output.

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `JRE_HOME` and `JAVE_HOME` to `/home/Desktop/jdk1.7.0_45` (the root of the JRE installation)

Answer (score 1):

You set JRE_HOME to `/home/Desktop/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java`. It should be set to `/home/Desktop/jdk1.7.0_45`: the root directory of the Java installation.